# Using a Pager adapter with ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

I am trying to create a welcome slider but there is a problem when calling `slideView.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);`. There is an error saying

> required type adapter, provided SliderAdapter

I am using `ViewPager2` and I was using the old `ViewPager` adapter. Is that a problem?

```
package com.example.leblood;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public SliderAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public int[] slide_images = {

        R.drawable.donat,
        R.drawable.request,
        R.drawable.bloodmap

};

public String[] slide_heading = {

  "Donate Blood",
  "Request Blood",
  "Track Requests"

};

public String[] slide_desc = {

        "You can donate at any time just by filling the form",
        "Request any type of blood anywhere in Lebanon",
        "Track blood requests, donation centers and pinpoint their location"

};


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_heading.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view,  Object object) {
    return view == object;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, container, false);

    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
    TextView slideDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_desc);

    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
    slideHeading.setText(slide_heading[position]);
    slideDescription.setText(slide_desc[position]);

    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem( ViewGroup container, int position,  Object object) {
    container.removeView((ConstraintLayout)object);
}
}
```

```
package com.example.leblood;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager2 slideView;
    private LinearLayout dots;
    private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        slideView = findViewById(R.id.SlideviewPager);
        dots = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dots);

        sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        slideView.setAdapter(**sliderAdapter**);
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dots"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SlideviewPager">

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/SlideviewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="779dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You need to extend to FragmentPagerAdapter for ViewPager2.  https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

Comment: You can use this example to implement welcome pages. 
https://www.androidhive.info/2020/01/viewpager2-pager-transformations-intro-slider-pager-animations-pager-transformations/

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager2` uses the `RecyclerView.Adapter` to provide its content. So you can either use the old `ViewPager` with your current adapter (which I wouldn't recommend) or migrate to the new one.

They actually provide a comprehensive [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) so I would recommend taking a look at that, especially if you've never used a `RecyclerView` before.